# Reproduce the geom_vline and geom_text in seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

In `R` with `ggplot2`, we can use `geom_text` and `geom_vline` to plot vertical lines and write annotations when plotting density or histogram charts with `facet_grid`.

In `Python` with `Seaborn`, is there any similar way to perform these tasks?

For example, how to add text `"Mean:xxx"` to the right upper corner in each of the subplot in the following example? How to add corresponding vertical lines for means in each subplot?

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="darkgrid")

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, row="sex", col="time", margin_titles=True)
bins = np.linspace(0, 60, 13)
g.map(plt.hist, "total_bill", color="steelblue", bins=bins)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a custom function that takes in a column in the data.frame as the first argument, and then you can plot the mean using `plt.axvline`. The text is a bit tricky (hope I got it correct); you need to use `plt.text` in [axes coord](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html):

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="darkgrid")

def geom_vline(data,**kwargs):
    ax = plt.gca()
    m = data.mean()
    plt.axvline(m, **kwargs)
    plt.text(0.8,0.8,"Mean= "+str(round(m)),horizontalalignment='center',
             verticalalignment='center',transform=ax.transAxes)

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, row="sex", col="time", margin_titles=True)
bins = np.linspace(0, 60, 13)
g.map(plt.hist, "total_bill", color="steelblue", bins=bins)
g.map(geom_vline,"total_bill", ls=":", c=".5")
```

[image]